# How to use rsync to preserve time of content but not the directory itself?

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm using rsync to update the content of a target directory `to` to be the same as a source directory `from`, i.e.: `rsync -rt --delete from/ to/`.
I want to keep the time for the files in `from`, and found the `--times`/`-t` switch.

However, this will preserve the time of the directory as well, making `to` has the same modification time as `from`.

I would like to avoid this behaviour specifically, because the `to` directory is shared across a user group with permission `771`, and other users (in the group) do not have the permission to modify the directory's modification time. Using rsync in this way will result in an error saying the time of `to/.` cannot be modified.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried `rsync -Ort ....` ?  That switch is on the very next line of the `man` page from the `--times` swtich.  If that still doesn't work, please [edit] your post to show: `ls -ld --full-time from/ to/` before; the exact `rsync` command you used and its output; and `ls -ld --full-time from/ to/` after.

Comment: @JimL. That seems to work. Thanks! Weird I didn't see that switch. If you put it as an answer, I'll choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-O` switch from the `rsync` man page:

`-O, --omit-dir-times        omit directories from --times`

```
rsync -Ort ....
```